# Firebase Unity Authentification for database service account configuration

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I noticed that I require a service account key for the firebase real-time database since I don't have public rules. Under the service account page, I have three service accounts(App Engine default service account,firebase-adminsdk, firebase-crashreporting).

Now my question is, which account I require for the EditorP12File or if I require a new service account for the user and if I require the new account, which roles it requires for the database and the authentification system(since I store it in the asset folder, it shouldn't have more rights than required for a client).

Thanks